# Politely refusing being walked to the door

Tags: phrase-request, politeness

Imagine you are at the doctor's office and at the end when you are done you are leaving the office and the doctor comes with you to the exit door and you want to say thank you to doctor and you say "doctor I am leaving please do not bother yourself by staying there. Ok it might take half a minute for me to be gone from the entrance of the door, okay? so there is no need you stay there for half a minute, probably you have something to do and that is very kind of you to stay there until I am gone. What can I say instead of saying "do not bother yourself doctor" ? Leave me here and I have gone in minutes, do not waste your time by staying here and showing respect to me. Close the door and go inside please" .

Comment: If the doctor wants to see you out and to watch you depart, then *depart*, don't keep him waiting too long.  A good way would be to thank the doctor and leave him in peace.  Telling the doctor to go about his business is **impolite**, however polite might be the words and phrases you want to use for that.

Comment: Actually it would take maybe 2 minutes 3 minutes for me to be gone and I need to say something so that he would not stay there and waste his time I need to say something and what expression can I use ? thank you in advance

Comment: Leave it to the doctor to spend as much time at his door seeing you leave as he *pleases*. It is **his time** for him to waste.

Comment: Any suggestion a native speaker might use , I just want to improve my English.

Comment: Something like "Thank you doctor for walking me to the door.  Have a good afternoon/evening."

Comment: In the US, this is a highly unlikely scenario. Doctors are generally much too busy.

Comment: @mkennedy Perhaps he is the last patient of the day and the doctor wants to lock the door behind the patient. But he also doesn't want to slam the door in the patient's face. You can see it could be awkward?

Comment: @Calchas Good point!

Comment: Yeah, my doctor always leaves the room before I do and I'm left there to gather up my stuff and mosey out to the lobby on my own time.

Answer (score 5):

You are right that this needs to be handled with a bit of care not to appear impolite. The doctor is taking the time to show you out, and it would be rude to decline his hospitality in an abrupt way. It would also be rude to press on his time by dawdling.

Therefore the best thing is to be honest: "**Don't wait for me doctor, it always takes me a couple of minutes to put my coat on!**" Or even, "**I can see you are very busy, so let's say goodbye here, thank you again.**"

In English we also have an idiom, "**I'll show myself out**", which arises in this scenario. It used to be proper to escort your guests out of your house personally. However, you should be careful when you use it, because it is often used sarcastically.

Answer (score 4):

As a native speaker, I would probably say something like, "I'm all set, then, thank you," or "Thanks again."  You cannot really tell the doctor to go away without being rude, but you can make clear that you need no further assistance/company.